# Swaping 2 chars using base addressing

Tags: mips

I'm having trouble seeing the difference between none base addressing swaps and base address swapping.
Here's the code I'm supposed to edit

Input : Apples

Output : pAlpse

```
.text
main:
#Prompt user for sting
    la $a0, promptStr
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #Get String
    la $a0, buffer 
    li $a1, 20
    li $v0, 8
    syscall
```

The code I have to replace with the base addressing method is here

```
#Initialize pointer to start of string (specify register)
    move $s0, $a0    

#Get a char from the string (register)
loop:   move $t0, $s0    
    lb $t1, ($t0) 

    #IF at end of the string branch to endStr
    beqz $t1, end    
    beq $t1, 10, end 

#Add 1 to the string pointer
    add $s0, 1       

    #get the next char in the string
    lb $t2, ($s0)   

#IF at end of the string branch to endStr
    beqz $t2, end    
    beq $t2, 10, end  

    #Swap the 2 chars by writing them back to the original string
    sb $t2, ($t0)    
    sb $t1, ($s0)    

    #Add 1 to the string pointer
    add $s0, 1
```

And ends here I'm pretty sure

```
#Jump back to loopStart     
    j loop

#Blankline
end:    la $a0, blankLine
li $v0, 4
syscall

#Display modified string
la $a0, promptEnd
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

la $a0, buffer
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #Exit porgram
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

.data
buffer      : .space 20
promptStr   : .asciiz "Input a String : "
promptEnd   : .asciiz "Modified String :"
blankLine   : .asciiz "\n"
```

I'll be trying to find out the difference but could someone help me understand by replacing the pieces I have to replace with notes explaining how it works with the difference. Thank you

Comment: Do you know C? It's the difference between using pointers to iterate and load elements from an array, as in `*string` and `string++` and using an index like `string[i]`, `i++`.

Comment: I don't know C but I understand now just a little bit more on what the differences are but its just the code is a little bit different using base addressing instead of a pointer. I just can't see it in code maybe idk. Sry

Comment: OK, well `add $s0, 1` is like `string++`, it moves the address in `$s0` forward one byte, so the next time you do `lb $t2, ($s0)`, even though you didn't use an offset, `$s0` points to the next character in the string. If you want to convert this to use an offset, never change `$s0` but use an index/offset to access different bytes, like `lb $t2 ($s0 + offset)` in pseudocode; you'll need to compute `$s0 + offset` using `add` and some other register to keep the index/offset and increment it. It's going to be a simple integer that runs from 0 to the string's length, stepping by 1 in the loop.